# Динамическое создание суммы

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Здравствуйте! Есть динамически создаваемый блок

```
    <input name="items[0].quantity" id="items0quantity" 
    style="width: 100%; display: none;" class="quantity-slider count" 
    data-slider-ticks="[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]" data-slider-value="8" 
    data-provide="slider" data-slider-handle="square" 
    data-slider-ticks-labels="[&quot;0&quot;,&quot;10&quot;,&quot;20&quot;,&quot;30&quot;,&quot;40&quot;,&quot;50&quot;,&quot;60&quot;,&quot;70&quot;,&quot;80&quot;,&quot;90&quot;,&quot;100&quot;]" 
    data-slider-min="1" data-slider-max="11" data-slider-step="1" 
    data-slider-tooltip="hide" data-value="5" value="5">
```

в `app.js` считываю по `id` и вывожу на экран

```
    var calculate = function() {
    var arrRes = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
    var index0 = parseInt($('#items0quantity').attr('data-value'));//0
    var index1 = parseInt($('#items1quantity').attr('data-value'));//1

    var total = arrRes[index0] + arrRes[index1];//2


    $('#changeCount .cost').text(total);
};
```

Но не могу придумать, как сделать так, чтобы строки `//0 //1` создавались динамически в зависимости от считываемого `id`

Comment: кто вызывает функцию `calculate`? Откуда будет считываться `id`?

Comment: вызывается функция `$('#changeCount .count').change(calculate);`. `id` будет считываться из динамически создаваемого блока, оно может быть, а может не быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно выбрать все поля по общему классу, и работать с ними.

```js
function getSum() {
  return $('.count')
    .map(function(){
      return $(this).val() | 0;
    }).toArray()
    .reduce((c, qty) => c += qty);
}
function update() {
  $('output').html(getSum());
}

$('.count').change(update)
```

```html
<input class="count" type="number"><br/>
<input class="count" type="number"><br/>
<input class="count" type="number"><br/>
<hr/>
<output></output>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```